# Best Practice : Import CSV to MYSQL Database using PHP 5.x

Tags: php, sql

what is the best solution to import large amounts of records into an MySQL or Oracle Database. I Think there are two ways :

- Insert every record with an persistent connection
- Create on BIG SQL-Statement and query the Database

Iam not sure wich is performing better ? Is there any Best Practice Solutions for this kind of operation ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one other possibility: [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'foobar.csv' 
INTO TABLE foobar
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

This requires that the MySQL server has access to the physical file. But moving/copying a file to an import directory should not be hard with PHP.

Comment: Thanks is also available in oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Import into MySQL you can use `LOAD DATA INFILE`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0):

Must admit I tend to use MySQL Administrator for most of my large database restores.
Not too sure about Oracle.
Also depends on the size and structure of your MySQL.

I'm talking a couple of GBs of SQL data.